# Tkinter Treeview showing extra column

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview

I am trying to add scroll bar to my tree view... But i cant figure it out how to do it with my existing code. Moreover i am getting an extra column at starting. can anyone tell me why i am getting this?

> > Tree View Code

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(formcontainer, columns=("name", "fathersname", 
"mothersname","rollno","studentid","contact","email","dob"))
tree.heading('name', text="Student Name", anchor=W)
 tree.column("name",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('fathersname', text="Father's Name",anchor=CENTER)
tree.column("fathersname",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('mothersname', text="Mother's Name", anchor=W)
tree.column("mothersname",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('rollno', text="Roll Number", anchor=W)
tree.column("rollno",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('studentid', text="Student ID", anchor=W)
tree.column("studentid",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('contact', text="Contact", anchor=W)
tree.column("contact",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('email', text="Email", anchor=W)
tree.column("email",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.heading('dob', text="Date of Birth", anchor=W)
tree.column("dob",minwidth=0,width=100, stretch=NO)
tree.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

> > Update Function

```
def updateview():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    t = ('Rahul',)
    records = c.execute("SELECT * FROM students")
    fatcheddata = tree.get_children()
    for elements in fatcheddata:
       tree.delete(elements)
       print (fatcheddata)

    for row in records:
       # print(row)
       tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSi11.png)

Comment: Yes heading problem solved... but how to add scroll bar?

Comment: [Adding Scrollbars to Widgets](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm#canvas) Pick one from [`[python][tkinter] treeview scrollbar`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+treeview+scrollbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first column is the "tree" part of the treeview. You can hide it by using the `show` method, which takes a string containing one or both of the words "tree" and "headings". If you don't include "tree", that column will be hidden.

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(formcontainer, show="headings", columns=...)
```

Comment: Thank this works.... Can you help me to add scroll bar?